# Check if ADODB connection is open

Tags: vba, oledb

I use the following from within some excel procedures to establish a connection to our database.

```
Private Const strConn As String = _
    "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1 ..."     

Sub OpenConnection()

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 0
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn

End Sub
```

In subsequent code I open the connection using various SQL strings.
I'd like to test if `rs` is open so I know that it needs to be closed but the following does not work. How can I change the condition in the following to work?

```
If (rs.Open = True) Then
    rs.Close
End If
```

The following works but I'd rather not use error trapping in this way:

```
On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

ADO Recordset has `.State` property, you can check if its value is `adStateClosed` or `adStateOpen`

```
If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
  If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

[MSDN about State property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Edit;
The reason not to check `.State` against 1 or 0 is because even if it works 99.99% of the time, it is still possible to have [other flags set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will cause the If statement fail the `adStateOpen` check.

Edit2:

For Late binding without the ActiveX Data Objects referenced, you have few options.
Use the value of adStateOpen constant from [ObjectStateEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
  If (rs.State And 1) = 1 Then rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Or you can define the constant yourself to make your code more readable (defining them all for a good example.)

```
Const adStateClosed As Long = 0 'Indicates that the object is closed.
Const adStateOpen As Long = 1 'Indicates that the object is open.
Const adStateConnecting As Long = 2 'Indicates that the object is connecting.
Const adStateExecuting As Long = 4 'Indicates that the object is executing a command.
Const adStateFetching As Long = 8 'Indicates that the rows of the object are being retrieved.    

[...]

If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then

    ' ex. If (0001 And 0001) = 0001 (only open flag) -> true
    ' ex. If (1001 And 0001) = 0001 (open and retrieve) -> true
    '    This second example means it is open, but its value is not 1
    '    and If rs.State = 1 -> false, even though it is open
    If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then 
        rs.Close
    End If

    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: ok - just guessing but is there a typo in the answer? ...let me try to edit...should it read `If (rs.State And rs.adStateOpen) = rs.adStateOpen Then ` : although I still don't understand this conditional statement. What will it be evaluating to if rs is open? `If (1 And ?) = ? Then`

Comment: It is bitwise `And` operation. The bit which is `adStateOpen` will only remain set if that bit in `.State` is set and all other bits are zeroed. Result of comparing the `And` operation value to `adStateOpen` will only result `True` if that bit flag was set in `.State`.

Comment: Heh, your confusion was probably in place. I did not mean to use `rs.adStateOpen` but `adStateOpen`.

Comment: I'm using late binding so `adStateOpen` bugs "Variable not defined" ...that is why I edited and added in `rs.`...although I think `rs` was the wrong edit - have re-edited.

Comment: ....hmmm still not working: can you edit your code so it functions without a reference; I use late binding.

Comment: Oh, Sorry! The Flags link I provided shows the list of constants where `adStateOpen = 1`. So yes, let me edit the answer.

Comment: surely `If (rs.State And 1) = 1 Then` is the same as `If rs.State = 1 Then` ?!

Comment: No, like I said it would work in most of the cases but there is a possibility you end up having it both open AND executing a command or fetching rows, in which cases the `.State` value would be `1+4=5(binary 0101)` or `1+8=9(binary 1001)`. You can use simple `If rs.State = 1` if you want, but why not do it right way which will work in all circumstances, no future hard-to-find bug situations.

Comment: I understand your answer now - thanks. As an aside - is there equal complexity when testing an object like `fConn` where earlier in the code I've executed `Set fConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` and then at the end I want to tidy up this object?

Comment: Yes, `ADODB.Connection.State` also uses `ObjectStateEnum`.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old topic, but in case anyone else is still looking...

I was having trouble after an undock event. An open db connection saved in a global object would error, even after reconnecting to the network. This was due to the TCP connection being forcibly terminated by remote host. (Error -2147467259: TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

However, the error would only show up *after* the first transaction was attempted. Up to that point, neither Connection.State nor Connection.Version (per solutions above) would reveal any error.

So I wrote the small sub below to force the error - hope it's useful.

Performance testing on my setup (Access 2016, SQL Svr 2008R2) was approx 0.5ms per call.

```
Function adoIsConnected(adoCn As ADODB.Connection) As Boolean

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    '#PURPOSE: Checks whether the supplied db connection is alive and
    '          hasn't had it's TCP connection forcibly closed by remote
    '          host, for example, as happens during an undock event
    '#RETURNS: True if the supplied db is connected and error-free, 
    '          False otherwise
    '#AUTHOR:  Belladonna
    '----------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    'Set up SQL command to return 1
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = adoCn

    'Run a simple query, to test the connection
    On Error Resume Next
    i = cmd.Execute.Fields(0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Tidy up
    Set cmd = Nothing

    'If i is 1, connection is open
    If i = 1 Then
        adoIsConnected = True
    Else
        adoIsConnected = False
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This topic is old but if other people like me search a solution, this is a solution that I have found:

```
Public Function DBStats() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
        If Not IsNull(myBase.Version) Then 
            DBStats = True
        End If
        Exit Function
    errorHandler:
        DBStats = False  
End Function
```

So "myBase" is a Database Object, I have made a class to access to database (class with insert, update etc...) and on the module the class is use declare in an object (obviously) and I can test the connection with "[the Object].DBStats":

```
Dim BaseAccess As New myClass
BaseAccess.DBOpen 'I open connection
Debug.Print BaseAccess.DBStats ' I test and that tell me true
BaseAccess.DBClose ' I close the connection
Debug.Print BaseAccess.DBStats ' I test and tell me false
```

Edit : In DBOpen I use "OpenDatabase" and in DBClose I use ".Close" and "set myBase = nothing"
Edit 2: In the function, if you are not connect, .version give you an error so if aren't connect, the errorHandler give you false

Comment: what is this: `.Version`? ....could you possibly add the code inside `myClass` ....I recently posted this, just the other week, so I would be VERY interested to see how you have written `myClass`: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116253/class-module-to-wrap-up-classic-ado-call-to-sql-server

Comment: ".Version" give you the version of the Database so if you not connect to a database (I use Access) you can't know the version so by this way you can know if you are connect to the database

Comment: This set me on the right track, but doesn't work in the case where the remote host has terminated the connection, as the version is still available and non-null. In these case the solution I just posted can be used.