# Verify SQL connection in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Gradually converting an application from classic .asp to .aspx and just got stuck on checking the database connection. The first bit of code works fine in my .asp application;

```
<%' use this meta tag instead of adovbs.inc %>  
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" uuid="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" --> 

' SQL database connection and result sets
Dim hSQLOne, RSQueryOne, SQLQuery

On Error Resume Next  

Set hSQLOne = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
hSQLOne.Open EMSGSRC
If hSQLOne.State = adStateOpen then 
    nSQLconnected = 1
    Processing...
```

but when I converted it to .aspx like this;

```
<%' use this meta tag instead of adovbs.inc %>  
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" uuid="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" --> 

' SQL database connection and result sets
Dim hSQLOne As ADODB.Connection
Dim RSQueryOne As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLQuery As String

On Error Resume Next  

hSQLOne = New ADODB.Connection
hSQLOne.Open (EMSGSRC)
If hSQLOne.State = adStateOpen Then
    nSQLconnected = 1
    Processing...
```

I get this error;

**Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'adStateOpen' is not declared.**

Ok, fair enough, tried removing the METADATA tag and just declaring the connection state constants within the application like this;

```
'---- ObjectStateEnum Values ----
Const adStateClosed As Short = &H0s
Const adStateOpen As Short = &H1s
Const adStateConnecting As Short = &H2s
Const adStateExecuting As Short = &H4s
Const adStateFetching As Short = &H8s
```

but **"If hSQLOne.State = adStateOpen Then"** doesn't match so it doesn't do anything.

Must have declared something wrong here or not checking the State properly.

Any help appreciated....

The very next day this post by @Raybarg [Check if ADODB connection is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611545/check-if-adodb-connection-is-open) solved it!

```
If (hSQLOne.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
    nSQLconnected = 1
    And do the stuff I want to do...
```

Comment: By "SQL" do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? You should abandon `ADODB` and use ADO.Net. And just curious, why are you "updating" a legacy app with a slightly less legacy technology? Webforms is not a modern platform.

Comment: Yep, MS SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder - why are you using ADODB instead of ADO.NET?

Comment: Thanks @Dai perhaps you could show me an example