# Is there a way to detect if establishing a data connection has failed using VBA before the warning message boxes appear?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

My concern is that there is a read-write lock in the file I want to connect to because it is being used by an application as shown:
[Locked MS Access File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwxBO.png)

When I try to refresh the data connection in MS Excel, these errors/notifications occur because it is unable to make a connection to the MS Access file that is being used:

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

[image: 4th]

I am wondering if there is a way for VBA to detect if establishing a data connection has failed. I have no idea how to approach it and the VBA code to refresh the query is shown below:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - MS Access File")
    .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
```

The connection string of my Excel data connection to a Access file is shown below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Test.MDB;
Mode=Share Deny Write;
Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the method `state` to check your connection:

```
if ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - MS Access File").OLEDBConnection.State <> 1 then
   ' Your connection is not ready
end if
```

Comment: Thanks @Vityala I took the code from C# and forgot to convert to VB

Comment: @kiks73 - you are welcome. However `ConnectionState.Open` is also a .net option. In VBA, the constant is simply `1` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17611807/5448626

Comment: @kiks73 Thanks for the answer although I get a `Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method` error. I use this code: 
`If (ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Test").OLEDBConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Open) Then
   MsgBox "Failed to connect"
End If`

Comment: @Pherdindy - see the answer from the comment above, it is quite well written.

Comment: @kiks73 The error must be somewhere in `.OLEDBConnection.State` I still get the same error. Is there any class or module I should retrieve? In the `OLEDBConnection` class in the `Object Browser` there is no member with the name `State`

Answer (score 0):

In VBA the `.IsConnected` is a boolean property which works like this:

`If ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - MS Access File").OLEDBConnection.IsConnected Then`

It helps taking a look at the VBA built-in libraries, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and looking for something meaningful:

[image]

[OLEDBConnection.IsConnected Property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oledbconnection.isconnected)

Comment: Thanks I never knew about the shortcut for the built-in libraries besides `F2`. Although my concern is: I have a refresh code in the `Workbook.Open()` method and is meant to refresh all data connections. By default everything is not connected when I open it, and i'm wondering if it's possible for VBA to actually catch if establishing connection has failed before all warning message boxes as shown in the main post appears. So I can do something like: `If connection has failed, then use this alternative method to connect`. I have a VBA alternative to bypass the failure but it's much slower